# Why write `sizeof(char)` if char is 1 by standard?

Tags: c, coding-style

I was doing some C coding and after reading some C code I've noticed that there are code snippets like

```
char *foo = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * someDynamicAmount);
```

So I want to ask what's more C-ish way to allocate memory for char array? Use `sizeof(char)` and supposedly future-proof the code against any standard changes or omit it and use the number directly?

Answer (score 67, accepted):

The more Cish way would be

```
char* foo = malloc(someDynamicAmount * sizeof *foo);
```

referencing the variable and not the type so that the type isn't needed.
And without casting the result of malloc (which is C++ish).

Comment: This is better because if the type of `foo` is changed it will still malloc the correct amount.  This is especially important to do this in a memcpy.

Comment: will the compiler know `sizeof *foo` in the value to the `*foo`'s definition?

Comment: "which is C++ish" - well, in the unlikely event that you use `malloc` in C++, you would have to cast the return value. I suspect that it was a misguided C idiom as well as, and perhaps before, being a C++ idiom. I find it amusing that there's a CERT advisory for C code saying that you should always cast the return value of malloc, and another one saying that you should never do so.

Comment: @Eimantas: yes, there's some text in the standard somewhere that the name of an object is available in its initializer expression. There aren't many cases where you'd use it, since the value is indeterminate, but this is OK since it doesn't use the value.

Comment: I must say I prefer to have the typedef included in the sizeof instead of a reference... i.e. malloc(sizeof(FOO) * count);

Comment: @Steve, I've know people using a C++ compilers to compile C libraries to use them more easily in otherwise C++ programs (some platforms had -- still have? -- problems with exceptions tranversing C code).

Comment: @James: the way I see it, you have the choice of repeating the type (which can become out of sync and introduce a bug), or repeating the variable name. Unless your variable shadows another one, changing the name of the variable and failing to update the malloc argument causes a compilation failure ("foo not defined"), so it's a safer kind of repetition.

Comment: @AProgrammer: yes, I've commented before that using the code you recommend for malloc is an excellent way to stop people doing that ;-) If they want a version of my C code that compiles as C++, they're welcome to fork it, but unless I'm going to be very careful to ensure that my code doesn't behave subtly differently as C or C++ (for example because `sizeof('a')` is different, or any of dozens of other incompatibilities) then I don't want it to even compile as C++...

Comment: @Steve, Purposely designing a library so that it can be compiled in C and in C++ is sometimes the right thing to do.  Thinking that compiling random C code with a C++ compiler will work without modification is an illusion.  But it is less trouble than making work a code developped on a 32 bit platform without paying too much attention on portability on a 64 bit platform.

Comment: @AProgrammer: yes, if I was writing it to work as both from the outset, then it's all OK. But if for example I don't ensure that before making a callback to user code, the `malloc`ed buffer is stored somewhere that I'll free it later, rather than that exception you mentioned being thrown over my call to `free`, then it's best to prevent the code compiling as C++. I guess that justifies calling the idiom "C++-ish", although I'd prefer to call it "frightful abomination that is multi-language-source-ish".

Comment: @Steve Jessop: Pre-C89, the `*alloc` functions returned `char *` instead of `void *`, so the cast *was* necessary.  That's part of why the practice has been so hard to stamp out; older programmers may still do it out of habit, and of course anyone who looks at their code or books written by them sees the practice and copies it.  Took me a while to stop doing it once I realized it was no longer necessary.

Comment: I would like to point out that doing this where `foo` is of type `void*` will not work properly if your compiler does not issue a runtime error (non-conforming compiler).

Comment: The proper C++ way would be to use `reinterpret_cast`, if you can't avoid using `malloc` in the first place.

Comment: @starblue "_use reinterpret_cast_" what?

Answer (score 28):

I do `sizeof(char)` to make the intentions clear. If anyone ever decides he wants foo to be an `int` he knows he'll need to do `sizeof(int)` for it to keep on working.

> > or omit it and use the number

Plus it's not very good coding practice to use magic numbers.

Comment: It's not magic numbers. I meant the variable which has some int value.

Comment: Even with the compiler set to emit all possible warnings, `int *foo = malloc(sizeof(char) * some_quantity)` will compile without complaint, silently creating a bug.

Comment: sizeof (*foo) is the way to goo

Comment: @Blrfl
Not necessary a bug - `int *foo = malloc(sizeof(char) * 4)` is a valid code for allocating memory for 32-bit integer ...

Comment: @0x69: That fails badly on systems where `int` is not four bytes or `char` is not eight bits.  The standard permits both, and both of those situations exist in the real world.  If you need an integer of known size, `<stdint.h>` provides types to handle that.

Comment: @Blrfl True, but still on systems where int is 4 bytes and char is 8 bits - my code will not create a silent bug like you said. It MAY create a bug, but that's not what you said...

Comment: @0x69:  "May" is just as severe as "will" if someone expects that building your code on any system with a standards-compliant compiler will result in a bug-free binary.  The standard provides mechanisms that guarantee correct behavior _everywhere_, and I can't see any legitimate reason to intentionally abandon them.

Answer (score 26):

IMHO the best practice is to write `sizeof(*foo)`. Then you're
 covered also if the type of foo changes and the sizeof is not corrected.

Answer (score 10):

Compare:

```
float*baz = malloc(sizeof(float) * someDynamicAmount);
int  *bar = malloc(sizeof(int)   * someDynamicAmount);
char *foo = malloc(sizeof(char)  * someDynamicAmount);
```

Vs:

```
float*baz = malloc(sizeof(float) * someDynamicAmount);
int  *bar = malloc(sizeof(int)   * someDynamicAmount);
char *foo = malloc(someDynamicAmount);
```

I like the first version. Do you prefer the second?

Comment: So in cases where the code snippet is part of a list that are so intrinsically related that you've horizontally aligned them -- so related that if you add one for `long long` later then you're happy for the diff to show 3 lines changed in addition to the one added -- *then* it's OK to write `sizeof(char)` ;-p

Comment: @Steve: It's not about the list. It's about not making an exception of the general pattern for char just because you happen to have a guarantee of its size.

Comment: you can look at it two ways, though. If you think of `malloc` as taking a "size in bytes" and `sizeof` as being the way to get the size of something "in bytes", then it makes sense to write `sizeof(char)`. But if you think of `malloc` as taking a "size in chars", then it makes no sense to write `sizeof(char)`, because no "unit conversion" is required. To that mindset, it's like writing `if (something() != false)`. I don't write `sizeof(char)` if I'm allocating a byte buffer for I/O or string manipulation. I would if the code was nearly generic, but happens to use `char` at the moment.

Comment: ... well, that is I would write something for the size. If for some reason it wasn't appropriate to write it AProgrammer's way, it would be `sizeof(char)`. In practice, for a read buffer I write `char *foo = malloc(BUF_SIZE);`, in that nearly-generic code I'd write `char *foo = malloc(sizeof(*foo)*ARRAY_SIZE)`. I won't add what I see as noise to my code, in order to treat the former as part of the same "general pattern" as the latter.

Comment: @Steve Jessop: programmers who are expert in a certain language will have trained their eye to spot potential wtfs of the language. Since almost all mallocs had to have sizeof(), if while skimming over code you see malloc without one, then you'll have to pause and look around for its type, and now you realize you have wasted your time pausing because it turned out to be a char. This pauses potentially breaks your flow of what you're currently thinking, and may accumulate. There is a merit in being consistent.

Comment: I don't think it's true in my code that almost all mallocs have a `sizeof()`. Does that affect your assessment? If you're allocating space for just one struct instance, do you write `malloc(sizeof(mystruct)*1)` on the basis that many mallocs are for arrays, and there should be consistency with those? I'd say that if this is consistency is really that useful to you, then you should use either `calloc` instead of `malloc`, or for performance a static inline function that wraps `malloc` using `calloc`s parameters.

Comment: Interesting as well that John Bode's answer puts the multiplicands in the opposite order to everyone else, suggesting that his code too is going to blow the minds of some readers.

Comment: @Lie Ryan - if I'm allocating a `char` buffer I don't normally add a `sizeof` expression.  Similarly, if I see a `malloc` without a `sizeof` expression, I assume it's allocating a `char` buffer; no break in my flow.  @Steve Jessop - that's because my way is the *right* way, since it reads more naturally (at least for people used to reading left-to-right ;-): I want N elements of this size.

Comment: @Steve Jessop: you're beating the wrong straw man, I have said nothing about the multiplier, also putting multiplication in the wrong order is not a wtf (unless you're working with matrices, but then again C do not have operator overloading to worry about). Try again.

Comment: @John Bode: if that's the case, if you've trained your senses to assume that a missing sizeof means you're allocating a char buffer, so you'll miss to spot the occasions where you really wanted the sizeof. (PS: your way wasn't the right way, C wasn't designed for people that reads from left-to-right, C was designed by people that [reads in spirals](http://en.islcollective.com/wuploads/preview/big_islcollective_spiral_reading_comprehension_text_65644db847e06f6fa2_64766385.jpg), as exemplified by the [variable type declaration](http://www.unixwiz.net/techtips/reading-cdecl.html) syntax :P)

Answer (score 8):

The common idiom is

```
T *p = malloc(N * sizeof *p);
```

or

```
T *p;
...
p = malloc(N * sizeof *p);
```

This way you don't have to worry about the type.

Answer (score 6):

You're correct, by standard, the multiplication is irrelivant.  That said, it looks like a habit someone got into to be consistent.  If you always use the `sizeof()`, regardless of type, you never forget.

```
char *foo = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * someDynamicAmount);
int  *bar = (int  *)malloc(sizeof(int)  * someDynamicAmount);
```

Answer (score 3):

Citing [C99 standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1124.pdf), section 6.5.3.4 *The `sizeof` operator*:

> When applied to an operand that has type **char, unsigned char, or signed char,**
>   (or a qualified version thereof) the **result is 1**. When applied to an operand that has array
>   type, the result is the total number of bytes in the array. When applied to an operand
>   that has structure or union type, the result is the total number of bytes in such an object,
>   including internal and trailing padding.

That is, `sizeof char == 1` by the standard, not by the implementation. Therefore it is absolutely correct to omit `sizeof(char)` when calling `malloc()` for chars and in similar cases. IMHO, it is highly improbable that future C standard will allow implementation-specific size of `char`, because too much code already depends on it to be 1 and backward compatibility is very important in C.

Therefore, the question is only about style, not correctness and here I support [AProgrammer's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7243925/252116).

Answer (score 2):

Writing `sizeof(char)` is not "future-proofing" your code against possible changes in the standard. It's usually a sign of complete misunderstanding of what `sizeof` means and the whole fundamental model of memory objects in C - what's referred to as *Representation of Types* in the language of the C standard. The **only** reason a `sizeof` operator even exists or makes sense is because C specifies objects to have a "representation" in memory in terms of a smallest possible unit that is `unsigned char`. If not for this, storage would be a lot more abstract and there would be no use of `sizeof` and the related pointer arithmetic.

`sizeof` is defined in *units of* `char`, i.e. `sizeof(T)==N` means type `T` occupies `N` `char`s. In light of this, `sizeof(char)` is completely silly; it's attempting to measure how many `char`s a `char` occupies.

Comment: sizeof is defined in bytes, not chars, chars are special cased for sizeof, but that's a different matter entirely than saying that sizeof is in terms of chars.

Comment: @jmoreno: -1'ing my answer doesn't change the fact that you're wrong. "Byte" is barely used in the C standard, and where it is used, it's synonymous with `char`. It probably wouldn't have been added at all if not for the phrase "multibyte character".

Comment: Actually, he's right, sizeof() returns the number of `char`s, not the number of bytes. `sizeof(char)` is `1`, by definition.

Comment: @R: C99 6.5.3.4 says `The sizeof operator yields the size (in bytes) of its operand` and `When applied to an operand that has type char, unsigned char, or signed char, (or a qualified version thereof) the result is 1`. I see it defined as bytes here.

Comment: Did you look up the definition of "byte" and "character"? See 3.6 and 3.7.1 and also 6.2.6...

Comment: @R - To what document are you reffering?

Comment: -1, for "It's nothing short of a complete misunderstanding...".  The fact that you don't see a reason to write it (because it's always 1) doesn't mean that other people who do are clueless.  Disagreement with you does not constitute "complete misunderstanding".

Comment: I agree the language was a bit too strong. I've changed it to "It's usually a sign of a complete misunderstanding..."

Answer (score -1):

This is all a matter of coding style. Several styles exist.

To actually answer the question, people write

```
malloc(n * sizeof(char))
```

to keep all their code that uses `malloc` consistent. Next time they might need `int` and then they can write the code in the very same way,

```
malloc(n * sizeof(int))
```

So the reason why it is done to keep the coding style consistent. Even though `sizeof(char)` is indeed guaranteed to always be 1 and is therefore superfluous. It is a way to write self-documenting code.

---

However, the most common way to use malloc in C is perhaps

```
type* t = malloc(n * sizeof(*t));
```

or 100% equivalent:

```
type* t = malloc(n * sizeof *t);
```

Since the operator of `sizeof` is not evaluated for side-effects, this code is safe, even though the variable `t` is not yet initialized.

---

The third possible style is the pedantically correct one, which would use *array pointers*, since what we allocate is actually arrays:

```
type (*t)[n] = malloc( sizeof(type[n]) );
```

This is perhaps the most correct way, as far as type correctness is concerned. The size of an array is allocated, and we point at the allocated array with an array pointer.

However, the problem with this style is that array pointers add extra complexity to the syntax: you would have to de-reference this array as `(*t)[i]` instead of `t[i]`. It makes the code harder to read. (And also as a side-note, if n is not an integer constant expression, the code won't compile on old, outdated C compilers.)

Answer (score -3):

The coding style can also be written as :-

```
char *foo = (char *)malloc(1 * someDynamicAmount);
```

But this is done so that the dynamically allocating memory can be increased according to the no of basic data type one wants. if u wanna increase 100 char it will increase 100 char. If may not have need but if we write 101 or 102 doing that would waste memory. doing the it according to the basic data type would not waste any memory space

Answer (score -3):

> The standard is deliberately vague about the sizes of common types. [[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_variable_types_and_declarations)]

While it is unlikely that the size of a `char` won't change, but the size of `short` *has* changed. The idiomatic way is:

```
type_t *foo = malloc(sizeof(type_t) * someDynamicAmount);
```

for any type (common or complex) type_t or

```
type_t *foo = malloc(sizeof(*foo) * someDynamicAmount);
```

So that you can decide to make changes to the type of foo later on and only change it in one place.

Comment: The standard garantee that `sizeof(char)` is 1.

Comment: @AProgrammer Sure, but then you have a consistency issue.

Comment: "A foolish consistency is the hobgoblin of little minds, adored by little statesmen and philosophers and divines". I'm already having this argument with Armen, but in almost all cases where I use a `char` buffer, there's no benefit of it being "consistent" with other arrays. I might almost as well observe that sometimes I write `malloc(strlen(x) + strlen(y) + 1)`, and start writing `malloc(sizeof(int)*(someDynamicAmount + 0 + 0))` for consistency.

Comment: And then I wen't on to give and explain the same answer as the answer with 35 up votes. And just because you pick `char` for you type now does not mean that your not going to decide to change to some kind of Unicode type later and need something other than char. Then you'll need to add back sizeof(type_t). And yes I have had situations where I started with an array of char and then went to something else after further work showed that char was insufficient for my uses.

Answer (score -8):

Think of unicode and multi-byte strings. If char represents single character in a string, it can actually occupy more than one byte, resulting in sizeof() > 1

Comment: -1 `sizeof (char)` is by definition 1. Multibyte representation of characters has nothing to do with it. This said, while `sizeof (char)` is always 1, `CHAR_BIT` may not always be 8. The sizes of base types must conform to this relation: `sizeof(char) <= sizeof(short) <= sizeof(int) <= sizeof(long) <= sizeof(long long)`.