# All combination of a char * in c?

Tags: c, algorithm, permutation

lets say I have in C the following string:

```
char * str = "1234";
```

Now I need all possible combinations of the letters:

```
12
13
14

21
23
24

...

123
124
132
134
142
143

213
214
231
234
241
243
...

412
413
421
423
431
432
```

I looked up for a solution and found permutations. But permutation ist not exactly what im looking for.
Does someone has a solution for this problem?

Comment: You're looking for the "powerset"

Comment: What problem exactly?  You haven't clearly stated *exactly* what you want.  For example, how would you count "11223344"?

Comment: Or rather, the permutations of the elements in the powerset it seems.

Comment: Looks like you need all permutations of all subsets?

Comment: Your desired result is all permutations of combinations, since you have `234` and `243` and `432`.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7441571/all-possible-combinations-in-a-string-in-c for just finding all combinations.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. Powerset bring the solution near to me. But the thing is that I need the combination sorted as shown in the example...

Comment: So what's the problem?  You generate the power set, turn each into a string, and sort by length (primary key) and lexicographic order (secondary key).

Answer (score 0):

While not sorted lexicographically, the following code will print all the permutations of the elements of the powerset of characters in the original string.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void swap(char* arr, int i, int j) {
    char t = arr[i];
    arr[i] = arr[j];
    arr[j] = t;
}

void permute(char *str, int i, int n) {
    for (int j = i; j < n; j++) {
        swap(str, i, j);
        if (!str[i]) {
            printf("%s\n", str);
        } else {
            permute(str, i+1, n);
        }
        swap(str, i, j); 
    }
} 

int main(void) {
    char str[] = "1234";
    permute(str, 0, strlen(str) + 1);
}
```

Using the bell algorithm, I generate all permutations of the characters in the original string **including the null terminator**. I then bake in a conditional that prints and aborts the current permutation when the null terminator is passed, to prevent printing duplicates of the same subset of the original characters.